# Copy value for one field to another (ACF - advanced custom fields) Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF - Advanced custom fields and I have two fields Price text (text field) and Price Filter (number).I want to achieve that when I enter a value in one field (Price Text field ) to automatically copy into another field (Price Filter field). Does anyone have an idea how to do this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced custom fields will add ids to your input fields in the edit screen. You can leverage that and create a small jQuery script that copies the content of your first field to your secondary field while you type. Something like this should work:

```
add_action('admin_footer', function () {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#acf-field_5c19647c09c56').on('keyup', e => {
    $('#acf-field_5c19648909c57').val(parseFloat(e.target.value));
  })
</script>
<?php
});
```

Remember to replace `acf-field_5c19647c09c56` with the id of your Price Text field and `acf-field_5c19648909c57` with the id of your Price Filter field.